# sql union irregular combo

Tags: mysql, sql

querying 3 tables, the last table has an extra row to look for.
tried this:

```
(SELECT 't1' AS tn, navid, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t1 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't2' AS tn, navid, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t2 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't3' AS tn, navid, title, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t3 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
```

i'd like to get the `title` field in t3
any help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it in the first two subqueries, with a value like NULL:

```
(SELECT 't1' AS tn, navid, NULL as title, clicks AS cc, tags 
 FROM t1 
 WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
       AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT 't2' AS tn, navid, NULL as title, clicks AS cc, tags 
 FROM t2 
 WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
       AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT 't3' AS tn, navid, title, clicks AS cc, tags 
 FROM t3 
 WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
       AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLs combined by [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) should have the same number and type of columns.

This is because you have only one result for the query even though it looks like multiple little queries.

So you have to have some values for the `title` column. You don't have it in `t1` and `t2`. So just select `null`:

`SELECT 't1' AS tn, navid, null as title, clicks AS cc, tags`...

```
(SELECT 't1' AS tn, navid, null as title, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t1 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't2' AS tn, navid, null as title, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t2 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't3' AS tn, navid, title, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t3 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to have same number of columns for UNION, also the columns names are based on first query, so you don't need to name the column for every query in the UNION

```
(SELECT 't1' AS tn, navid, '' As title, clicks AS cc, tags 
FROM t1 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't2', navid, '', clicks, tags 
FROM t2 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 't3', navid, title, clicks, tags 
FROM t3 
WHERE DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL '0 8' DAY_HOUR) <= NOW() 
AND tags LIKE '%cars%' )
```